# Why doesn't this svg curve animation adapt to browser width change?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I animated an svg curve using Javascript, and it works great! However, when you resize the window, it doesn't resize to fit it. Is there any way to do this? I am open to any solutions, whether it is CSS, JS, or HTML (or another language, for that matter). Here is the code I am using:

```js
    const vw = document.body.clientWidth
    const vh = document.body.clientHeight
    let wave = -2890
    function add(){
      if(wave === -2){
        wave = -2890
      } else {
        wave = wave + 2
      }
      document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = `<div class="wave" id="main" transform="rotate(1)"><svg width="${vw}px" height="25px" viewBox="0 0 1440 25" preserveAspectRatio="none"><g width="${vw}px" data-svg-origin="0 0" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1, ${wave + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) -10},0)" style="transform-origin: 0px 0px;"><path width="${vw}px" fill="currentColor" d="M 0 12.5 q 360 -25 720 0 t 720 0 t 720 0 t 720 0 t 720 0 t 720 0 V 0 H 0 V 12.5"></path></g></svg></div>`
      requestAnimationFrame(add);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(add);
```

```html
<div class="wave" id="main"></div>
```

For example, if you run the code snippet **not** in full screen, and then enter full screen, you can see that it stays with its initial width.

Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move the variables inside the function:

```js
let wave = -2890

function add() {
  let vw = document.body.clientWidth
  let vh = document.body.clientHeight
  if (wave === -2) {
    wave = -2890
  } else {
    wave = wave + 2
  }
  document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = `<div class="wave" id="main" transform="rotate(1)"><svg width="${vw}px" height="25px" viewBox="0 0 1440 25" preserveAspectRatio="none"><g width="${vw}px" data-svg-origin="0 0" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1, ${wave + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) -10},0)" style="transform-origin: 0px 0px;"><path width="${vw}px" fill="currentColor" d="M 0 12.5 q 360 -25 720 0 t 720 0 t 720 0 t 720 0 t 720 0 t 720 0 V 0 H 0 V 12.5"></path></g></svg></div>`
  requestAnimationFrame(add);
}
requestAnimationFrame(add);
```

```html
<div class="wave" id="main"></div>
```

Comment: Hmmmm I can't seem to get this to work when manually resizing window, is there a cause for this?

Comment: @divinelemon any particular browser? it seems fine on my side

Comment: Sorry, the issue had something to do with my cache. I cleared it and now it works!!!! Thanks so much!